# How to configure Eclipse Formatter to add this. in front of class members

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

How can I configure the Eclipse Formatter to add `this.` in front of every class member use? I can't find this in the Formatter configuration and Google does not give me reasonable answer.

I need this:

```
public class Foo {
    private int bar;

    public void methodUsingBar(){
        bar = 1;
    }
}
```

To be formatted to this:

```
public class Foo {
    private int bar;

    public void methodUsingBar(){
        this.bar = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Eclipse Preferences go to *Java* -> *Code Style* -> *Clean Up*. Create or edit an (active) profile. In the Profile Edit dialog go to the *Member Accesses*. Configure the settings in the *Non static accesses*-group as wished. In your case enable *Use 'this' qualifier for field accesses* and check *Always*.